# Mono: System.ServiceModel missing from /usr/lib/mono

Tags: c#, wcf, mono

Anyone know why I might be missing this assembly? 
It doesn't seem to be anywhere in the filesystem. I'm running Debian wheezy.

I'm trying to set up a build environment, I first installed `mono-xbuild` with APT then `mono-complete` after my build reported it couldn't resolve `System.ServiceModel`.

And yes, the csproj does reference System.ServiceModel.

Many thanks

Comment: what version of mono?

Comment: @DanielA.White 3.12.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a package for this assembly. Depending on your Mono/ NET Version configuration:

https://packages.debian.org/de/wheezy/libmono-system-servicemodel4.0-cil

I could not find a version below 4.0. This may be the only version existing (If I remember correctly, there should be nothing for 2.0 because the support of mono was dropped)

Comment: Thanks. The docs suggest its included with the standard mono package so still somewhat confused